# Creating a word document from a standard sharepoint list item

Tags: list, document-library, document-template

Can anyone point me in the right direction. I have a list in Sharepoint 2007 which is not a document library. From an item in the list, I can attach files quite happily using thestandard features. Now I'd like to be able to create word documents based on word templates, populate some data from the current item into the meta data, then be able to save the document back into a separate document library. The item in the document library will then need to be displayed in the current item, much like the attachments do already.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a custom Content Type using the Document Content type, and setting a document library to use this content type.

The fields you add to the custom content type (that inherits from Document, remember), will show in the Document Information Panel in Word, and you can add them as Quick Parts in the document. Save it as a template and associate the template with the Document Library.

This way you can create a new file in that library, it'll open with the template - and you can either enter info in the quick parts which will be save to the Content Type Columns when you save the file - or save the file first, update the columns from your content type in the library and open the file to see your quick parts all populated.

Basic steps:

- Create a site column for each metadata column you want.
- Create a custom Content Type which has Document as the parent. Add the site columns you just created.
- Create a Document Library. In Advanced Settings, turn on Management of Content Types. Add your custom Content Type.
- Upload a starter Word document, and set its content type to your Custom content type. Open this file and the columns should hopefully appear when you add a Quick Part. Save it as a 'template' (.dotx) and associate this with the Document Library through the Library's settings.

Here's a tutorial I've found form a quick google: http://docupoint.wordpress.com/2006/12/08/content-types-document-information-panel-and-quick-parts/

Search around for "SharePoint 2007 Content Types Document Information Panel" to see what other info can be found if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible

- move to document library follow @james 's answer
- if you need keep the data in list and users create and edit the data in list, document library is just a attachment lib. you can flow the **additional** steps:

  1. create a column in the list to storage doc URL.(i think the column type should by URL)
  2. write eventhandler to sync data from list to lib. when item added, create a document in library, and set the columns of document, save the document URL in the column; when item updated, get the document by the URL column, and update the columns of document.

the result:

when users view the item in list, he/she can see the document link in DisplayForm, when they click the link, the document will download (of course can DIRECTLY open, use scripts).
and the document is up to date !

Comment: Think this might also be achievable with a SharePoint Designer Workflow, too, if you want to keep away from C# code.